# Doubt proving equality of norms on Riesz-Kakutani Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

If X is a Compact Hausdorff topological space and $\mathcal{A}$ is its Baire $\sigma$-algebra, for every Baire measure $\mu$ the operator $\Phi_{\mu}\in C(X,\mathbb{R})^{*}$ has the same norm as the total variation of $\mu$. It is easy to prove that $||\Phi_{\mu}||\leq |\mu|(X)$ but i haven't been able to prove the other inequality.

I am following the proof given by Richard B. Holmes on his book Geometric Functional Analysis

> measure theory that each Baire measure is regular (in the sense that
>    its value at any Baire set $A$ is the supremum of its values on the
>   compact Baire subsets of $A$ ), and that every Baire measure can be
>   uniquely extended to a regular Borel measure.
>
> If $\mu$ is a Borel (or Baire) measure then as has already been noted
>    in $9 \mathrm{C}$ the mapping $(22.4) \quad x \mapsto \int_{\Omega} x
>  d \mu, \quad x \in C(\Omega, \mathrm{R})$ defines an element
>    $\Phi_{\mu} \in C(\Omega, \mathrm{R})^{*},$ and
>    $\left\|\Phi_{\mu}\right\| \leqslant\|\mu\|_{v} \equiv|\mu|(\Omega)(10
> \mathrm{D}, \mathrm{Ex} .$ 3). Now we claim that if $\mu$ is regular
>    then actually $\left\|\Phi_{\mu}\right\|=\|\mu\|_{v} .$ To see this,
>   let $\varepsilon>0$ and select disjoint Borel sets $A_{1}, \ldots,
> > A_{n}$ in $\Omega$ such that
>   $\sum_{1}^{n}\left|\mu\left(A_{i}\right)\right|>$
>   $|\mu|(\Omega)-\varepsilon .$ Let $C_{i}$ be a compact subset of
>   $A_{i}$ such that $|\mu|\left(A_{i} |
>  C_{i}\right)<\frac{\varepsilon}{n}$ and let $\left\{\mathcal{O}_{1},
> \ldots, \mathcal{O}_{n}\right\}$ be a family of disjoint open sets
>   such that $C_{i} \subset \mathcal{O}_{i}$ $i=1, \ldots, n .$ Because
>    $\mu$ is regular we may assume that $|\mu|\left(\mathcal{O}_{i} |
> C_{i}\right)<\frac{\varepsilon}{n}$ $i=1, \ldots, n .$ By Urysohn's
>    lemma there exist $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n} \in C(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$
>   such that $0 \leqslant x_{i}(t) \leqslant 1, t \in \Omega, x_{i}(t)=1,
> > t \in C_{i},$ and $x_{i}(t)=0, t \notin \mathcal{O}_{i} .$ Hence if we
>   put $x_{0}=\sum_{1}^{n}
> \operatorname{sgn}\left(\mu\left(C_{i}\right)\right) x_{i}$ we find
>   that $\left\|x_{0}\right\|_{\infty}=1$ and
>   $\left|\Phi_{\mu}\left(x_{0}\right)-\right| \mu|(\Omega)|<\varepsilon$

but i do not understand why the function $x_0$ has norm 1 and neither
why it is in $B_{\epsilon}(|\mu|(X))$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $x_0$ has norm $1$ because it is a sum of functions that have disjoint supports, and these functions all have norm $1$. I'm not sure what your second question is, but I interpret it as asking why $\Phi_\mu(x_0)$ is $\epsilon$ close to $|\mu|(X)$. The answer to that is however the entire construction, $\Phi_\mu(x_0)$ is equal to $\sum_i \int_{C_i} x_0 + \int_{X-\bigcup_i C_i}x_0$. The second summand is close to $0$, the first summand is $\sum_i \mathrm{sign}(\mu(C_i))\mu(C_i) = \sum_i |\mu(C_i)|$, which is close to $\sum_i |\mu(A_i)|$, which is close to $|\mu|(X)$.

Comment: That was helpful!. Using an $\epsilon/3$ argument i could write the answer formally. I assume is the same proof in the complex case. However, i am not sure why the compact sets can be assumed to be non-zero measure. I think is due to the fact that they approximate the $A_{i}$'s measure as much as we want.

Comment: It is not necessary for $C_i$ to have non-zero volume (if it has zero volume then $A_i$ will have very small volume, which is sometimes necessary, for example in the case of a pointmeasure), you can extend the function $\mathrm{sign}(0)=0$ so that all expressions remain well defined. For the case of complex measures you should use the complex conjugate of the argument of $\mu(C_i)$ instead of the sign in the expression and everything should work out.